# A name for a square matrix that its entries sum up to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a name for a square matrix which its entries ssum up to zero? Also, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are $n \times n$ matrices. And we do $X+Y$. Can there be a matrix $C$ that $CY = X+Y$?

Comment: You might want to check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, the answer is yes:

Consider the case where $C=I$ (matrix with ones on diagonal) and $X=0$ (all zero matrix).

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your second question: You want to know, given $Y$, which matrices $X$ have a solution $(C - I)Y = X$. This is equivalent to $Y^T(C^T - I) = X^T$, which in turn is equivalent to understanding when a matrix equation $YZ = X$ can be solved for $Z$.  But this is secretly just asking for several solutions of the form $Yz = x$, all pasted together. Each column of $Z$ can be thought of as a vector that, when multiplied by $Y$, gives the corresponding column in $X$. And each of these equations is completely independent of the others. So $YZ = X$ can be solved precisely when all the columns of $X$ lie in the image of $Y$.

So the original question can be solved precisely when the rows of $X$ lie in the row-span of $Y$.